# Time series converting non stationary to stationary and deal with negative values

Tags: python, time-series

I have a time series problem to forecast prices, and the target column is non stationary, but to convert it to stationary I differenced it, but I am getting negative values. My issue is, what do I do next?
Do I forecast with these negative values?
or what do I do, since prices cannot be negative, I am confused, and need help

Comment: Can you take the absolute value of the difference so it is positive?

Comment: This is probably a question that belongs on [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com).  There may already be an answer there if you look...

Comment: @Simon would taking the absolute make sense?

Comment: @mark Probably not, but it helps combat the negative value.

Comment: Price changes can be negative. Build a model to forecast the price change each time step. See ARIMA/ARIMAX models for example.

Comment: @Bill so something like growth or drop of the price?

Comment: Yes. That is one way to remove a trend because your model can incorporate a 'drift' in the mean. Did you look at ARIMA / ARIMAX methods as I suggested? Also, here is a good introduction to the issue: [How to Remove Trends and Seasonality with a Difference Transform in Python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/remove-trends-seasonality-difference-transform-python/).